# Regular expression to remove html tags and characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, string

I need help with a regex which will remove all html tags and characters from the string.

In my code shown below, I've oldStr :

[image]

On click of the 'Replace' button, I'd want to change the oldStr to 'Hello' and remove '<', '>' and any sort of html tags as shown in my string.

How could I achieve that?

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var oldStr = '&lt;p&gt;&lt;a&gt;Hello&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt';
  $('#old').text(oldStr);
  $('#replaceBtn').click(function(){
    var newStr = mystr.replace('&lt;', '');
    $('#new').text(newstr);
  });
});
```

```css
div{
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="old"></div>
<br />
<div id="new"></div>
<br />
<button id="replaceBtn">Replace</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. https://jsfiddle.net/vineeshmp/do83rje2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var oldStr = '&lt;p&gt;&lt;a&gt;Hello&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt';
  $('#old').text(oldStr);
  $('#replaceBtn').click(function(){
    var newStr = $('<textarea />').html(oldStr).text();
    $('#new').text( $(newStr).text());
  });
});
```

Comment: It just creates a dummy textarea element and automatically decode the html.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```js
var oldString = '<p><a>Hello</a></p>';

var newString = $(oldString).text();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please note that my oldStr is going to remain the way I've mentioned in the my code above.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldStr =  '<p><a>Hello</a></p>&gt';
var indexStart = oldStr.search("H");
var indexEnd = oldStr.search("o");
var newStr = oldStr.substring(indexStart,indexEnd +1);
```

Comment: Please note that my oldStr is going to remain the way I've mentioned in the my code above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

Quick run down:

turns the `&lt;` and `&gt;` characters into a much easier to read format. We do this so that we can get rid of the tag's or any information in them much easier.

I'm sure there's a faster way to replace both of them than chaining the method like I did, but I just woke up so this is what came out.

Next is the regex, which is sort of a mess but let me try to explain it:

"Find anything between the inequality symbols, but don't be greedy -- match the first one you find **OR** match anything of the format '&(some word characters);'" then we just replace anything that matches that with an empty string. What you are left with should just be a string containing what would be the text of the element.

For an alternative, you may just want to follow the first two `replace` calls and then just use Nimish's answer, which I feel would be much more reliable as jQuery's HTML parser is miles better than what I wrote.

```js
var oldStr = '&lt;p&gt;&lt;a&gt;Hello&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;';
var newStr = oldStr.replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>').replace(/(<(.*?)>|&\w+;)/g,'');
alert(newStr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```